# Compare the two file and move the different records in third file

Tags: unix

HI I have one more brain twister for you all; I have 2 text files, I need to find the diff in row and to write in third file but under the same partitions.

for example:

File :1

```
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Activity 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Schedule 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Linkage 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh , ,~~~ UPSTREAM PENDING/YET TO START ~~~ , , 
#############################################################################################################################
```

File :2

```
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Activity 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Schedule 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Linkage 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_audt_trxn_refnc_uld.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,04:41:49 ,Mar 17,04:43 ,SUCCESS 

d_isso_actvy_log_uld_cln.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

#############################################################################################################################
```

Output File:

```
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Activity 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Schedule 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB STATUS - Linkage 
==================== ============================== ======================== ==============================
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS
```

In the above 2 files(file1 & file2) the 3 & 4 row is different for all the 3
partition, so i want to write the 3 & 4 row frm file2 only to a new file
(Output file). SO i need a script which find the non matching row between two
file and to write in third file under the same partition.

I tried with the below query but iam not able to get the output result under
corresponding partition

```
awk 'NR==FNR && !/^=/{a[$0]++;next} !/^=/{if(/^JOB /){y=$0;tmp getline;print tmp;print y}if(!a[$0]){print $0}}'  file1 file2
```

I am getting output like below but I need output like Output file:

```
JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

JOB NAME ,ODATE ,START ,FINISH ,STATUS 

d_voy_svc_sesn_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS 

d_svc_evt_sumry_ld_ctm.ksh ,20110317 ,Mar 17,03:20:49 ,Mar 17,03:31 ,SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the diff tool from the command line. Filter the output with a tool like sed or grep and then redirect it to a destination file.

Answer (score 0):

`comm -1 file1 file2 | sed 's/^\t//'` maybe?  (You may need to use a literal tab instead of `\t`:  `Ctrl-V`, `Tab`.)

Comment: Hey this is only giving the difference between two file, which can be achive by my code itself, but i need the different record under the corressponding header

Comment: Erg, thinko.  It should be outputting common lines and lines only in the new file; but that of course includes the data that didn't change as well as the headers, meaning it's identical to the new file.  You want a script which copies through the headers and otherwise only outputs entries from the new file that either aren't in the original at all or have changed.  Hopefully that description tells you how to proceed.

Comment: Can u help me with a script to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **diff** tool. see the [man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) page for help.